# Нужно написать функцию , которая будет считать сколько гласных (на англ языке) в строке (Си)

Tags: c, строки

Вместе с мейном пожалуйста , строка которая отправляется в функцию должна сначала считаться с клавиатуры.

Вот , что сделал сам , но не работает:

```
int nr_vocale(char a[])
{
    int i,n,s=0;
    char *sir=a;
    n=strlen(a);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if ((a[i] >= 'A' && a[i] <= 'Z') || (a[i] >= 'a' && a[i] <= 'z'))
        {

            if (a[i] == 'a' || a[i] == 'A' ||
                a[i] == 'e' || a[i] == 'E' ||
                a[i] == 'u' || a[i] == 'U' ||
                a[i] == 'O' || a[i] == 'o' ||
                a[i] == 'I' || a[i] == 'i')
                s++;
        }
    }
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    char litera,*sir;
    scanf("%s",sir);
    printf("%s",sir);
    int n;
    n=nr_vocale(sir);
    printf("%d",n);
}
```

Comment: Наверное, нужно... Я же так понимаю, именно в этом вопрос - *"Нужно написать функцию , которая будет считать сколько гласных (на англ языке) в строке (Си)?"* :)

Comment: @MrShef  И какие проблемы?

Comment: А что вы уже сделали сами (кроме бегом написать сюда, чтобы все сделали за вас)?

Comment: Убрать вопросительный знак - я не это имел в виду, когда спрашивал, что вы сделали сами :)

Comment: @Harry Добавил , что сам напробывал

Comment: Совсем другое дело...

Comment: @Harry Вроде немного работает , но при условии что строка без пробелов , если ввожу 2 слова , то считает только у первого , как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int nr_vocale(char a[])
```

Лучше просто `int nr_vocale(const char *a)`

```
{
    int i,n,s=0;
    char *sir=a;
    n=strlen(a);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
```

Это лучше заменить на

```
    for(char *c=a; *c; ++c)
```

А это -

```
    {
        if ((a[i] >= 'A' && a[i] <= 'Z') || (a[i] >= 'a' && a[i] <= 'z'))
        {

            if (a[i] == 'a' || a[i] == 'A' ||
                a[i] == 'e' || a[i] == 'E' ||
                a[i] == 'u' || a[i] == 'U' ||
                a[i] == 'O' || a[i] == 'o' ||
                a[i] == 'I' || a[i] == 'i')
                s++;
        }
    }
```

на

```
    if (strchr("AEOUI",toupper(*c))) ++s;

    return s;
}


int main()
{
    char litera,*sir;
    scanf("%s",sir);
```

И куда вы читать собрались? `sir` указывает в никуда, память не выделена... Данный `scanf` читает только одно слово... Лучше уж

```
char sir[256];
fgets(sir,256,stdin);
```

Остальное и так сойдет :)

```
    printf("%s",sir);
    int n;
    n=nr_vocale(sir);
    printf("%d",n);
}
```

Пробуйте, собирайте [все в одно целое](http://ideone.com/ejqVBF)...

Comment: Можно пояснить как это for(char *c=a; *c; ++c) и toupper(*c) работают?

Comment: Первое - цикл посимвольно, пока не доберемся до нулевого символа (смещаем указатель `c` на следующий символ), а второе - стандартная функция, которая переводит символ в верхний регистр (для английских символов, как и запрошено в условии).

Comment: Что-то типа такого `s = strpbrk(s, "abcde");` не лучше?

Answer (score 1):

Данное предложение

```
scanf("%s",sir);
```

имеет неопределенное поведение, потому что указатель `sir` не был инициализирован, и не была выделена память, где будет храниться вводимая строка.

```
char litera,*sir;
            ^^^^^
```

Программа может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N   100

int main(void) 
{
    char s[N];

    printf( "Enter a string: " );

    if ( fgets( s, sizeof( s ), stdin ) != NULL )
    {
        size_t n = 0;
        char *vowels = "aeiou";

        for ( char *p = s; *p; ++p  )
        {
            n += strchr( vowels, tolower( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) != NULL;
        }

        printf( "There are %zu vowels in the string\n", n );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Например, если ввести `Hello World!`, то вывод на консоль будет

```
Enter a string: Hello World!
There are 3 vowels in the string
```

Если хотите оформить подсчет гласных в виде отдельной функции, то она может выглядеть как

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define N   100

size_t nr_vocale( const char s[] )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    const char *vowels = "aeiou";

    for ( ; *s; ++s  )
    {
        n += strchr( vowels, tolower( ( unsigned char )*s ) ) != NULL;
    }

    return n;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[N];

    printf( "Enter a string: " );

    if ( fgets( s, sizeof( s ), stdin ) != NULL )
    {
        size_t n = nr_vocale( s );
        printf( "There are %zu vowels in the string\n", n );
    }

    return 0;
}
```